# Logstash improperly parsing time stamp as json field

Tags: logstash

We have been ingesting logs from an MDM for approximately 2 years.  Recently, the MDM folks upgraded security on their (Windows) hosts.  Logstash previously showed <6> March 29 HH:MM:SS AirWatch... as the beginning of message.  With the security updates, Logstash is now interpreting this as a field within _source.

When we send this to Elasticsearch, it quickly tells us we have more that 1,000 fields and crashes.

Need help on how to either delete this entry (the log receipt time stamp is sufficient) or to insert a field in front of the entry as a consistent field.

We can make the change in message with mutate / gsub, but it has no impact on _source and the incorrect "field".

Comment: What is your pipeline configuration and how does your original message looks like? Update your question with more information. The `_source_` field is create by elasticsearch with the original json sent to index, not by logstash.

Answer (score 0):

changed codec from default (json) to line.

Getting clean input now.